# Magento2 translating Javascript (KO) template text

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, inline-translations, js-translation

I am trying to add a translation for the text `<!-- ko i18n: 'Store credit available' --><!-- /ko -->` present in `vendor/magento/module-customer-balance/view/frontend/web/template/payment/customer-balance.html`, but if I try to change the text in my `i18n/en_US.csv`, still its not working.

I have flushed the cache and and used static content deploy.

Is there a different way to add translations for KO templates ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

So I was finally able to figure out the problem.

Seems that the JS template translation are read from `js-translation.json` which is generated during `setup:static-content:deploy` execution. In order to populate data in this file a new **language package** has to be created for the project.

So instead of adding the CSV at the theme level like `app/design/<area>/<vendor>/<theme-name>/i18n/xx_XX.csv` we need to add it in the language package.

To create a new **Language Package** first from `project document root` we will need to create the following directories:

```
mkdir -p app/i18n/<project-name>/<xx_xx>
```

> **Important**: USE lowercase DIRECTORY NAMES ONLY camcelcased folder names will not work

Then change directory to the newly created folders:

```
cd app/i18n/<project-name>/<xx_xx>
```

Now you can create a `composer.json` (optional) file with the following content:

```
{                                                     
    "name": "<project-name>/<xx_xx>",                             
    "description": "<sample description>", //Ex:English (United States) language
    "version": "<version-number>", //100.0.1                             
    "license": [                                      
        "OSL-3.0",                                    
        "AFL-3.0"                                     
    ],                                                
    "require": {                                      
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"                
    },                                                
    "type": "magento2-language",                      
    "autoload": {                                     
        "files": [                                    
            "registration.php"                        
        ]                                             
    }                                                 
}
```

Next create we need a `language.xml` file with the following contents:

```
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>xx_XX</code> <!-- example: <code>en_US</code> -->
    <vendor><project-name></vendor>
    <package><xx_xx></package> <!-- example: <package>en_us</package> -->
</language>
```

After than `registration.php` containing the following content is needed:

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    '<project-name>_<xx_xx>',
    __DIR__
);
```

Now we can create a our translation CSV. If you already have one inside the theme folder something like `app/design/<area>/<vendor>/<theme-name>/i18n/xx_XX.csv` you can just move it to `app/i18n/<project-name>/<xx_xx>/xx_XX.csv`

Now from the `project document root` we need to run these commands:

```
find pub/static -name js-translation.json -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

> We need to delete the `js-translation.json` which has been already
>   created before running the `setup:static-content:deploy`

Now we run static content deploy:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy <xx_XX>
```

Once thats done we clear the cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

We can verify if the translation files for JS template has been generated by finding all the `js-translation.json` inside the pub/static folder.

```
find pub/static -name js-translation.json
```

This will provide the list of all the translation files generated for JS templates.

> Reference:
>
> 1. [Magento DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#m2devgde-xlate-severalpacks)
> 2. [Related Github Issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2056)

Comment: In my project `js-translation.json` files are created correctly from static content deploy even if .csv files are inserted in `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme-name/i18n/xx_XX.csv`. The only care is delete all `js-translation.json` before run static content deploy.

Comment: Which version of magento are you on ?

Comment: Vender/Theme so from this what should be <project-name> as per your above code??

Comment: @KaushalSuthar Project name can be anything you want, just make sure that it is in all lower case

Comment: Yes just did it and working fine (y) thanks....

Comment: Is this really the only way to do this? I mean, even the documentation (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html) states that we should be able to put translation files into `design/<vender>/<theme>/i18n/xx_XX.csv`.

Comment: @GielBerkers this is only needed for JS translation, as the magento 2.0.X doesnot take the design/<vender>/<theme>/i18n/*.csv to generate the js-translation.json.

Comment: helpful, worked for M2 EE 2.1.1. couldn't Imagen  that the solution would be by creating a translation package

Comment: Nice, this actually works. Btw, the composer.json file is not needed. I could leave it out and it still worked.

Comment: In 2.15. in my custom theme design/vendor/theme/i18n/de_DE.csv translations didn't work at all. It just takes the translations from app/i18n/...
You don't need to deploy static content btw. if not deployed they are created on the fly which is very handy for development. Just delete all js-translation.json once.

Comment: Magento 2 has a lot of bugs related to this, for us the best way has been to manually create a script that creates the `js-translation.json` file and make web server configuration that delivers it on the right kinds of requests

Comment: @AtishGoswami, Could you please look into my question and provide some suggestion.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307308/magento-2-knockout-js-translation-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment442618_307308

Comment: This is an invaluable answer, can I gift rep?

Answer (score 1):

As I described in the Github issue (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7525#issuecomment-316690100) there is another (easier) solution to that problem.

You just need to make sure to deploy every language separate.

So instead of using:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US de_DE it_IT fr_FR es_ES
```

use

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy it_IT
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_ES
```

This is probably caused by the fact that the `static-content:deploy` only compiles the files once and copies them afterwards to other languages.