# Magento 2 - Form Validation Translation

Tags: magento2, localisation, form-validation

I have a problem with magento 2 forma validation translation.

Not all fields are translated. (The Geburtsdatum and E-Mail field)

[image: Validation translation missing]

In my translation file de_DE.csv

```
"Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com).","Bitte gib eine gültige E-Mail an."
```

But this doesn't work. Anybody an idea what's wrong?

EDIT:

With language pack it works, but i have trouble with date messages.

```
"Please enter a date.", "Gib bitte ein Datum ein."
"Please enter a valid full date.", "Gib bitte ein gültiges Datum ein."
"Please enter a valid month (1-12).","Bitte gültiges Monat eingeben (1-12)."
```

"please enter a valid date/year" works.. thats strange

Comment: For Javascript text translation in Magento2, you need to follow a different way - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121251/magento2-translating-javascript-ko-template-text this should help

Comment: thanks that helped me, but i got problem with a few translations.   see my edit

Comment: You will have to run static content deploy everything you make a changes in your language pack .CSV file. Also make sure that you delete the `js-translation.json` file before running static content deploy using `find pub/static -name js-translation.json -exec rm -rf {} \;` after this run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and after that check if the new translation are being transferred to the `js-translation.json` file. To find the translation do `find pub/static -name js-translation.json`

Comment: hey, i made everything, but i cant translate those values.  could this be a magento bug?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be bug. I did some digging into the codebase and found those sentences which are not getting translated are not enclose in $.mage.__(), hence not getting translated. See file vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/validation/validation.js

Comment: Hi Umfi. I'm having a problem like this, please help me if your problem has been answered