# Magento2, after deploy in another language the generated js-translation.json is empty

Tags: magento2, localisation, knockoutjs

All translations are fine but JS templates are not translated. I realized that `/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/nl_NL/js-translation.json` is empty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the current `js-translation.json` and then try to run the static content deploy again. May need to clear Browser Cache and Magento Cache.

For the translation, we should read more: [Magento2 translating Javascript (KO) template text](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121251/magento2-translating-javascript-ko-template-text)

Comment: Now I got it with one line only but in FE is still in english {"Add to Cart":"balabla","You have no items in your shopping cart.":"blabla on tyhj\u00e4."}  , cache is cleaned

Comment: @Zinat how you translate in your Knock out template? Please, add proper code lines?

Comment: @Zinat should read more here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121251/magento2-translating-javascript-ko-template-text

Comment: All I did was creating the language package then setting the locale in admin panel. Then I delpoyed in nl_NL. Is there additional step for Knock out template translation? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html

Comment: I checked the link you sent and I have all those files

Comment: I'm going to go, tomorrow I will check your issue again.

Comment: I did not do any changes but it's fine now!!!

Comment: I try to translate another word(retaled to ko template) in the csv file of the language package, after deploying and cleaning cache the js-translation.json does not contain the new traslation!!!

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure that you have the correct file & folder permission in magento 2 folder.

Then Please do static content deploy then also please give permission once again.

Please follow this procedure and let me know.

Comment: Now I got it with one line only but in FE is still in english {"Add to Cart":"balabla","You have no items in your shopping cart.":"blabla on tyhj\u00e4."}

Comment: Zinat, also Khoa is right. Please follow the Khoa's procedure and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Steps based on Koha's solution:

```
1- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US nl_NL
2- Delete (only)file pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/nl_NL/js-translation.json
3- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL
```

Even without emptying the cache it worked perfectly