# Registering new language to solve JS translation

Tags: magento-2.1, language

I have tried to solve translation problem in magento 2.1 how it was shown in thread: [Magento2 translating Javascript (KO) template text](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121251/magento2-translating-javascript-ko-template-text)

Now any page created in magento contains:

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'latviski_lv_lv',
    __DIR__
);<!doctype html>
<html lang="lv-LV">
    <head >
        <script>
    var require = {
        "baseUrl":
```

Of course also functionality in admin panel is not working anymore. I believe there is some mistake in registration.php shown in that sample.

Is there any possibility to unregister my translation or remoove that faulty code?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add php mark at document begining in your registration.php?

```
<?php

    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'latviski_lv_lv',
    __DIR__
);
```