# Magento2: Translation Mini Cart Strings

Tags: magento2

I am trying to translate and localize strings in the mini cart. It is not working doing it the standard way (csv in i18n).

It seems a different approach is used then standard strings in the code.
E.g.

`<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('My text ')) ?>`

See image.

[image]

How can this be translated?
Thank you for your input.

Comment: You can check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121353/32947

Comment: Your link refers to JS translations, but this is merely a phtml template file.

Comment: It's not like phtml template file, it's a KnockoutJs html template file. So you need to use Js translation to translate them. Please try it out.

Comment: This worked flawlessly @QuanLe. Thank you!