# Magento 2- How to translate text in Knockout .html file

Tags: magento2, frontend, knockoutjs

**I want to translate KO text.**

```
"You have no items in your shopping cart."  "Empty Basket"
```

Already tried with translate.csv it doesn't work.

Is there any way to translating knockout template text in magento2?

Comment: your text is in html template or js file ?

Comment: knockout html file.

Comment: can you put your sample code ?

Comment: @SanjuAntala can you try  : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121251/magento2-translating-javascript-ko-template-text

Comment: May be you need to flush cache and static content deploy.

Comment: @kunj already did flush and clean still not showing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can try this its work for me.

```
find pub/static -name js-translation.json
```

Add your translation in theme `js-translation.json`

***For Example:***

```
{"You have no items in your shopping cart.":"Empty Basket"}
{"Forgot Your Password?":"Forgot Password?"}
```

Once that's done we clear the cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: It's working thanks, man! Can you explain where can locate that file in my theme?

Comment: @SanjuAntala 
its auto-generated file, no need to copy that. 
Just add your text in translate.csv than clean your cache

Comment: Thanx @Chetan its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
<!-- ko i18n: 'You have no items in your shopping cart."  "Empty Basket' --><!-- /ko -->
```

Translate it into  ***i18n*** directory of your module.
& last thing is make deploy.

```
 rm -rf pub/static/frontend
 php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
 chmod 777 -R var/ pub/static generated/
```

Comment: Wt happen when multiple texts translate? 
check @chetan above answer its works for me and it's easy to solution.

Comment: Thanx, dude! For Replay...