# Magento 2 knockout js translation is not working

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, js-translation, locale-translation

I'm using Magento 2.3.4

I'm looking at the translation issue for the last few days but I didn't get any answer.

I have used mageplaza one step checkout module.

Very recently I have upgraded the magento version to 2.3.4. previously I have 2.3.3.

Now the js translation on the checkout page is not working. But my custom phtml and php via translation were working fine. But only the knockout js translation is not working.

See the below screen.

[image]

I have checked the js translation file from *pub/static/frontend/Fillme/default/de_CH/js-translation.json*

On this file, the translation was reflected perfectly.
Eg : "Shipping Address":"Lieferadresse",

But in the frontend, it showing like Shipping Address.

There was an **i18n translation** available in one step checkout module itself and in my custom language package also.

Can anybody help on this issue

Comment: do you try replacing it with translate="'Shipping Address'" in html

Comment: @YasirLatif, I have tried this too. It also not working for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this step.

1. Clear cache.
2. Delete file js-translation.json in the pub folder.
3. Remove the browser’s cache in browser local storage (include
   mage-translation-file-version and mage-translation-storage ).

If your problem didn't resolve, please let me know.

Comment: @Skuynet, I have followed the above steps and it doesn't help for me. The translation file was rendered perfectly. But it is not showing in frontend

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the above-mentioned issue.

In my case, the issue was in lib folder. I have tried to upload magento 2.3.4 lib folder on my local environment. And it's working. So, I conclude that, while upgrading the magento version, the library folder was not successfully upgraded. May be of any permission issue or something. I'm not sure about that.

So, in later anybody have such an issue, keep this step in your debugging scenario.